# How to read failed plugin report?

Tags: osgi, jira-plugin

I'm creating simple plugin using example provided [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/learn-the-development-platform-by-example/create-a-plugin-skeleton) - simple servlet. As far as I know JIRA Plugins are OSGi Framework based.

During deployment of my plugin (`atlas-run` command) I recive error message which I'm unable to understand. This is output which I have found on my console:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ___ FAILED PLUGIN REPORT _____________________
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     1 plugin failed to load during JIRA startup.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]       'com.my.soft.my-work-log-plugin' - 'My Work Log Plugin'  failed to load.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           Cannot start plugin: com.my.soft.my-work-log-plugin
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]               Unresolved constraint in bundle com.my.soft.my-work-log-plugin [164]: Unable to resolve 164.0: missing requirement [164.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=bsh)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           It was loaded from C:\Users\pduleba\work\repo\my-jira\my-software-maven-plugins\my-software-jira-plugins\my-work-log-plugin\target\jira\home\plugins\installed-plugins\my-work-log-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Whats the meaning of this:

```
Unresolved constraint in bundle com.my.soft.my-work-log-plugin [164]: Unable to resolve 164.0: missing requirement [164.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=bsh)
```

Is there any way to change log level i.e. DEBUG? How to do it?

Where can I found more meaningful logs?

Thank You for any piece of advice!

Comment: I have found [troubleshooting](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/faq/troubleshooting) and [--log4j](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/working-with-the-sdk/command-reference/atlas-run) switch for `atlas-run` command which might be helpful in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error from OSGi that says, essentially:

1. The bundle `com.my.soft.my-work-log-plugin` imports a package named `bsh` (which is BeanShell I think?).
2. There is no package named `bsh` being exported by any installed bundle.

It seems like you have to install the BeanShell bundle, as this is a dependency of your bundle.

Comment: Ok, thank You for details @Neil Bartlett